# Tailwind + NextJS some classes don't work when run build script

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

When I run dev script it works fine. For example, my className = "flex max-w-screen-2xl lg:ml-auto lg:px-12 xl:px-28" when i build, only flex works

Comment: When I had an issue that only happened in the production build it was related the the fact that next will rename all of the components. This is a wild guess but maybe somewhere in the code you are comparing a string to check the type of a component? Are the class names the same for both production and dev?

Comment: Thank you so much, but actually I just forgot to add a directory to the purge option !

Comment: @phonx Please add your solution as an answer to this question. That will help people coming to this post in the future.